# Javascript- Web Bluetooth API GATT Error: Not supported

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth-lowenergy

This question might have been asked by many people, but I have no luck to get answer from researching.

My ultimately plan is running a web app with Web Bluetooth API in smartphone with FLIC button to control audios to play. One click, play one audio.

I'm testing the program in my MAC laptop with my iPhoneX first, because I'm thinking if I can get both of them connected, then when I run the web app in smartphone, then I can connect to the FLIC button.

However, I got this error.

`Something went wrong. NotSupportedError: GATT Error: Not supported.`

Am I missing something? I saw someone mentioned [iPhone cannot connect Latop](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7844265?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), hopefully this is not true

Below is the code:

```
$("#bluetooth").on("click", function(){
        const controlServiceUUID = '00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'; // Full UUID
        const commandCharacteristicUUID = '00002a0f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'; // 
        var myCharacteristic;
        navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            acceptAllDevices: true,
            optionalServices: [controlServiceUUID]

        })

        .then(device => {
            console.log("Got device name: ", device.name);
            console.log("id: ", device.id);
            return device.gatt.connect();
            console.log("Here");
        })

        .then(server => {

            serverInstance = server;
            console.log("Getting PrimaryService");
            return server.getPrimaryService(controlServiceUUID);
        })

        .then(service => {
            console.log("Getting Characteristic");
            return service.getCharacteristic(commandCharacteristicUUID);
        })

        .then(characteristic => {
            // 0x01,3,0x02,0x03,0x01
            myCharacteristic = characteristic;
            return myCharacteristic.startNotifications().then(_ => {
                log('Notifications started');

             myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', test);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong. " + error);
        });

     function test(event) {
           if (myCharacteristic) {
               myCharacteristic.startNotifications()
               .then(_ => {
                   console.log("Notification stopped!");
               })
               .catch(error => {
                   console.log("Argh!" + error);
               });
           }
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Web Bluetooth API is only available on ChromeOS and Android 6 or later with flag option.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API)

Answer (score 1):

Different platforms are at different points in implementation.  I have been using this repo for updates on the status of the API:

[WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md)

Note the lack of support for ios

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fixes your problem (i'm working on muse eeg), but one "hack" to get rid of this error is to wait some time (e.g. 500ms) after each characteristic write. Most platforms don't support write responses yet and writing multiple commands in parallel will cause this error.

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md

Answer (score 0):

Is your command characteristic UUID filled in incorrectly? Try replacing it with one that can be written?

```js
const controlServiceUUID = 0xfff0; // Full UUID
const commandCharacteristicUUID = 0xfff4; //
```